# build.gradle.kts:10:28: Unresolved reference: settings

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have seen examples for using "by settings" delegation in build.gradle.kts scripts, but no matter what I have tried to do, Gradle complains that settings is an unresolved reference.  If I change 'settings' to 'project', Gradle is happy.  Has the use of 'by settings' been deprecated?  I looked in the Gradle 6.4.1 manual and it shows this delegation.  I've attached an image showing a simple Spring Boot app generated by Initializr with the only changes being the addition of the gradle.properties file and the delegation in the build.gradle.kts file.  I'd really appreciate any hints about this issue...  I know that I can use 'extra' properties or finding the property against the project object, but, frankly, this issue has annoyed me to the point that I need to know what is wrong! :P. Thank you for any help...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `project` delegate is defined in the class `ProjectDelegate`. Your build script is evaluated against an instance of `KotlinBuildScript` which extends `Project`, so the delegate is available.

However, when `settings.gradle` is evaluated, projects aren't configured yet, so there's no instance of `KotlinBuildScript`. Instead, the script is evaluated against an instance of `KotlinSettingsScript` which extends `Settings`, which has the `settings` delegate. I don't think this delegate was ever available to project build scripts.

In both cases the delegate is provided by an extension function, because both `Project` and `Settings` are Java files part of the Gradle core API.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas!